# Conversion of dBm/Hz into watt

Tags: noise, power-spectral-density

I have a noise power density of -174dBm/Hz and a bandwidth of 180kHz. How to convert the resultant noise into watt. I am confused.

1. First, multiply (-174dBm/Hz) by 180000, then convert the result into watt?
2. First, convert (-174dBm) into watt, them multiply it by 180000?

Thank you,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First, multiply (-174dBm/Hz) by 180000, then convert the result into watt?

Because the decibel is a logarithmic unit, you need to be careful here.  $-174\mathrm{dBm}$ means $10^{-17.4} \mathrm{mW}$.  Common usage of the decibel tends to mix operations, so $-174\mathrm{dBm/Hz}$ means $10^{-17.4} \mathrm{mW/Hz}$

You can *really* complicate your units by *adding* $10 \log_{10} 180000$ to your $-174\mathrm{dBm}$.  I prefer not to do that, because it makes dimensional analysis strange, and I routinely find errors in my calculations by being careful to always use dimensional analysis.

> First, convert (-174dBm) into watt, them multiply it by 180000?

Not quite.  First, convert $-174\mathrm{dBm/Hz}$ into $\mathrm{W/Hz}$, carrying units all the way.  *Then* multiply by $180000\mathrm{Hz}$ (*not* a bare 180000), cancelling units where you can.  *Then* double-check that your result is *actually in watts*, at which point you have that extra measure of confidence that you haven't divided where you should have multiplied, or visa-versa.

Answer (score 2):

You would use the second method suggested by the OP.

dBm uses a power ratio relative to 1 mW (specifically as $10\log_{10}(P_{in}/1\text{mW})$. To convert -174 dBm/Hz into Watts/Hz, you could either subtract 30 dB to get -204 dBW/Hz (where dBW uses a ratio of Watts) and then reverse the dB by dividing by 10 and raising to the 10th power, or equivalently reversing the dB first to get power in units of mW and dividing that by 1000 to convert mW to Watts.    (Dividing by 1000 is the same as subtracting 30 dB since $10\log_{10}(1000)= 30$.

In summary for the two methods converting the power spectral density would be:

$$-174 \text{ dBm/Hz} - 30 \text{dB} = -204 \text{ dBW/Hz}$$
$$10^{-204/10} \approx (3.981E-21) \text{ Watts/Hz}$$

$$10^{-174/10}/1000 \approx (3.981E-21) \text{ Watts/Hz}$$

The above is the power density. To get the total power, if we assume the given density is constant across the bandwidth, we then simply add in dB $10\log_{10}(BW) = 10\log{10}(180E3)= +52.5 \text{ dB}$ prior to reversing the dB to get the total power in Watts, since power is directly proportional to bandwidth.  This is consistent with the 2nd method the OP has suggested, where we could alternatively multiply the figure converted by dB by 180,000. Multiplying the power quantity by 180,000 is identical to adding 52.5 to the dB quantity.

Doing this results in the correct total power in Watts:

$$-174 \text{ dBm/Hz} - 30\text{ dB}  + 52.5\text{ dB} = -151.5 \text{ dBW}$$
$$10^{-151.5/10} \approx (7.08E-16) \text{ Watts}$$

$$10^{(-174+52.5)/10}/1000 \approx (7.08E-16) \text{ Watts}$$

Comment: That gets you to Watts per Hz, but the OP is looking for the power over a 180kHz bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tool that computes [dBm/Hz integrated over a user defined bandwidth and presented in either dBm or Watt](https://www.onesdr.com/dbm-hz-to-dbm-and-watt-calculator/)